# Which one is larger, $\int^1_0 f(x) \ln f(x) dx\,$ or $\int^1_0 f(s) ds\, \int^1_0 \ln f(t) dt\,$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> If $f$ is a positive measurable function on $[0,1]$, which one is larger, $$ \int^1_0 f(x) \ln f(x) dx\,$$ or $$ \int^1_0 f(s) ds\, \int^1_0 \ln f(t) dt\,$$

I tried putting in some functions and found that $$\int^1_0 f(x) \ln f(x) dx\,$$ is larger , but I'm not able to prove in general.

Comment: It can go either way depending on what function you are having.

Comment: what will be the function for other way around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \log f(x)$ and notice $\log z$ is increasing for $z \in (0,\infty)$, we have:

$$( f(x) - f(y) )(g(x) - g(y)) \ge 0,\quad\forall (x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$$

This leads to

$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^1\int_0^1 ( f(x) - f(y) )(g(x) - g(y)) dx dy \ge 0\\
\iff &
\int_0^1\int_0^1 ( f(x)g(x) + f(y)g(y) ) dxdy \ge \int_0^1\int_0^1 ( f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x) ) dxdy\\
\implies & \int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx \ge \left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_0^1 g(x)dx\right)
\end{align}
$$